# Performance issue: Recalculating Styles takes 200ms in PDF.js

Tags: css, google-chrome, pdf.js

Hi i try to implement subj plugin into my site.

I test this plugin on external file with the next line of code ( and plug-in is pretty fast:

```
%iframe{src: '/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/tracemonkey.pdf', style:'border: 0', width:'100%', height:'100%', frameborder:'0', scrolling:'no'}
```

But when i implement my own file ( which is in my own folder in the project ) 
This plugin become very slow.

```
%iframe{src: '/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/system/uploads/deal/download_document/24/aaaaa/some.pdf', style:'border: 0', width:'100%', height:'100%', frameborder:'0', scrolling:'no'}
```

#### Screenshots

Left image: Timeline for External (fast) file (35ms for 1271 elements)
Right image: Timeline for Internal (slow) file (196ms for 7737 elements):

[image: External (fast) file]
[image: internal (slow) file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This performance hit is caused by [grab-to-pan.js](https://github.com/Rob--W/grab-to-pan.js), a library I've written for PDF.js to implement the Hand Tool feature. When the mouse is pressed, the library toggles a class name on the `<html>` element, to change the cursor (from "grab" to "grabbing") via CSS:

```
.grab-to-pan-grabbing * {
    cursor: url("grabbing.cur"), move !important;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing !important;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing !important;
    cursor: grabbing !important;
}
```

This method appears to have a significant effect on performance, so I have changed the way of updating the cursor. See https://github.com/Rob--W/grab-to-pan.js/commit/e0f893753ac10a5c97159fd01155b05d234f4c0f for the changes. A few tests shows that the new method is over 100 times faster. I've submitted the patch to PDF.js as [PR #4209](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/4209).

Comment: After applying your changes i saw performance - but it is still very slow. Problem was using wiked_PDF for generation of PDF file. For some reasons, all pdf generated by this gem is very slow when try to use pdf.js plugin. I Solved this problem by changing the generator of pdf ( wiked_pdf to unaconv )

Comment: @DemitriyDN By "it is slow", are you referring to the original bug ("Recalculating Styles"), or something else? Create an issue at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js and include a link to the "slow" PDF(s)? Then we can try find the bottleneck and improve the performance.

Comment: I solved this problem with changing WikedPDF(wkhtmltopdf) to Unoconv pdf generator